# Python multiple condition IN string

Tags: python

How to merge the condition in array format

```
lines = [line for line in open('text.txt')if 
        '|E|' in line and
        'GetPastPaymentInfo' in line and
        'CheckData' not in line and
        'UpdatePrintStatus' not in line
        ]
```

like

```
lines = [line for line in open('text.txt')if 
        ['|E|','GetPastPaymentInfo'] in line and
        ['CheckData','UpdatePrintStatus'] not in line]
```

Comment: You can't; the list won't be `in` the `line`. You *could* use `all`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) within [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function to check the membership for all elements :

```
lines = [line for line in open('text.txt') if 
        all(i in line for i in ['|E|','GetPastPaymentInfo'])and
        all(j not in line for j in ['CheckData','UpdatePrintStatus'])]
```

Or if you want to check for words you can split the lines and use [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) method in `set` <sup>1</sup>:

```
lines = [line for line in open('text.txt') if 
        {'|E|','GetPastPaymentInfo'}.intersection(line.split()) and not {'CheckData','UpdatePrintStatus'}.intersection(line.split())]
```

Note that you need to put your words within a `set` instead of list.

---

<sub>1) Note that since `set` object use *[hash-table](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwi7vraygorGAhXL7RQKHW0_APw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHash_table&ei=Cr56VbuRJsvbU-3-gOAP&usg=AFQjCNFWP9iBvqhV_h73-y04O6NM6tIsNQ&sig2=TamEpxV8twqQPR5XIfk_MA&bvm=bv.95515949,d.ZGU)* for storing its elements and for returning the items as well, checking the membership has O(1) order and it's more efficient than `list` which has O(N) order.</sub>